# pattern matching using python where result becomes pattern

Tags: python

I have a csv file with one column containing expression delimited by '='. 
Example.

```
a= if(b is true , c, false)
....
c= if (x  >0 ,true,false)
....
x= 100
```

I am trying to build all possible workflow from the expression enlisted in the csv file and then print as a list of expression in sequence which will allow me to see the calculation path such as for **a**. In this case when user search for **a** result will be RHS of the expression which in turn have to be parsed and used as expression ( **b** and **c** ).  So first search result becomes the pattern matching for next step.

```
a= if(b is true , c, false)
c= if (x  >0 ,true,false)
x= 100
```

I am checking out Python to achieve this and I am going through regex right now. 
How to do this in python ?. Please provide your suggestions.

Thanks!